# Jeep patriot 2.0crd manual 2007 4wd

Tags: jeep, 4wd, awd, patriot

I have a Jeep patriot 2.0crd manual 2007 with 4wd. Since i bought it i have never used the 4wd switch but yesterday i did a bit off roading. I switched off the esp by holding the button for 5 seconds until 'esp off' appeared on the dash and pulled the 4wd switch. No 4WD indicator light appeared on the dash. Apparently the 4wd switch does nothing. The button/switch lights green when I turn on the headlights but when I pull it, no inicator appears on the dash to inform me that 4wd is engaged.
Could you help please?

Comment: Well, perhaps the indicator does not work but 4WD does... Until you start checking and I suggest start with the fuses for the 4WD control and work from there...

Comment: The light is not burnt. There is a way of checking the lights. Will check fuse first thing in the morning! Thank you!